# How to assign same values to different properties at same time in JSON file?

Tags: json

I have a JSON file with same values for different property names. Is there a way I can add all properties same values at once.
For Example my JSON file is:

```
{
"x":{
"one":"abc"
},
"y":{
"one":"abc"
},
"z":{
"one":"abc"
}
}
```

Is there a way to assign all x,y,z at once like (I know this is wrong way, but Is there a different way to achieve this)

```
{
"x","y","z":{
"one":"abc"
}
}
```

Comment: No. JSON does not allow this. JSON is a very simple declaration language, and not allowing for syntactic tricks like that is part of what makes it simple.

Comment: What you _can_ do is use an array instead of an object, but that requires application code that reads or writes your JSON to know what array indexes correspond to which fields.

Comment: [JSON](https://json.org) is a text representation of some data structure. It does not have properties, assignment or anything else a programming language has. In order to process it (other than store or transfer), it needs to be parsed. Through parsing, a data structure similar to the one used to generate the JSON is created. The thing you want to get doesn't make much sense in a programming language. Your question looks like an [XY problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/66377/281242) to me. What do you want to achieve? A smaller JSON? Less code to create the data structure? Something else?

Comment: @axiac Yes, I want to know if there is a way to make smaller JSON.

Comment: There isn't any way to remove the duplicate values unless you design the data structure to accomplish this goal. Or you can compress the generated JSON when you save it into a file (but it needs to be uncompressed before it is parsed). But there is no need to compress if the JSON is the answer to an HTTP request; in this case the web server can help and compress the data sent through the network, if it is configured properly and if the browser accepts compressed content (they do without problems). All in all, in this case the solution is much easier (it requires configuration, not code).